# Javascript Object.entries index issue

Tags: javascript, object

For `Object.entries`, Why is the `0` index giving me item on index `1` ?

```js
const object3 = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(object3)[0]);
// expected output: Array ["2", "b"]
```

Is there something with the random keys ?

Comment: the keys, who could be indices of an array are sorted before other keys of the object.

Comment: Can you explain further ?

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149345/1447675

Comment: I don't know if JS *sometimes* giving this guaranteed order according to a specific algorithm other than creation/insertion order was a good idea. There's certainly some benefit, yet the behavior can seem mysterious.